# How do I find the period of the function $\tan{\pi/2[x]}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How do I find the period of the function? $$\tan{\frac{\pi}{2}[x]}$$ What are the factors that I must take care of?

(Maybe its simple but i'm not getting it methodically.$2$ seems to work though)

[] is greatest integer function.

Comment: The period of $\tan(x)$ is $\pi$. Therefore, the period of $\tan\left(\frac xa\right)$ is $a\pi$.

Comment: oh sorry i meant greatest integer function. @KennyLau

Comment: You do realize that your function is not defined, when $[x]$ is odd, and is equal to zero otherwise :-)

Comment: Therefore, the period of $\tan\left(\frac\pi2x\right)$ is $2$. Since $2$ is an integer, this is also the required period.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Awesome logic ;-)!Silly of me not to realize that :-P!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph it using [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).
$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\text{floor}(x)\right)$$
Now, it's easy to see that this is $0$ when $\text{floor}(x)$ is even and undefined when $\text{floor}(x)$ is undefined, so we have a period of $2$.

Comment: Thanks :-) That graph was helpful!